# Is this a woman imitating a robot or a real robot?

Tags: robotics

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMz2bSSM_8M&feature=youtu.be) shows a supposed robot shown on Tokyo Game show for the presentation of PlayStation4 game.

The robot (if it is one) looks so realistic that it looks hard to believe it really is a robot. I mean I've watched other videos about robots and even the ones that claim to present realistic robots are nowhere near to the realism of this robot.

Maybe they have an over the top technology to make it or spent a lot of money and time on details.

On the other hand it could just be a scam and it could be a hired woman that is acting like a robot.

I've watched the video in detail and I cannot get a conclusion as it shows some things that from my point of view are too complex for a robot to do or have, while others look robot like.

Hope I can get help here with my doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a human model. The act is a marketing stunt to promote the game ["Detroit: become human"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit:_Become_Human) which features such androids as characters you play.

You can clearly see less "androidy" androids in this other movie from the same expo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su0rfH0dZa4

In particular you can also see the clearly fictional slogans appearing, such as "Take one home today", and the game title.

In other words, this is a game being presented, at a game expo, that features androids. They are actors.

Comment: I think that you are trying to say that this is a woman imitating a robot, but you don't actually say that.  Could you please take the extra step and answer the question asked?